# When writing a new SOAP web service why would I choose to use version 1.2 over 1.1?

Tags: soap

The numerous technologies for writing SOAP web services allow me to create services which adhere to either SOAP 1.1 or 1.2. It's not clear to me what benefits 1.2 provides over and above 1.1. This leads me to the conclusion that I should always use 1.1 to accommodate the largest number of compatible clients.

Why would I choose to create a SOAP 1.2 rather than a SOAP 1.1 web service?

Comment: This depends in part on your platform. If you were using .NET, I'd say, just write your WCF service, and you're done: change the configuration if you need different protocols, and don't change the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From practical standpoint this is the case when you don't need SOAP1.2 if you're happy with 1.1, at least for now.

1.2 is quite different standard, its messages are infoset-based and (most notably) it is protocol-agnostic (you can use your own binary protocol for message delivery) and it is not backwards-compatible with 1.1.

[You could read more here.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/ae/cwbs_soapverdiffs.html) Note the "Related information" section.